# Keep data in memory or use database

Tags: sql, database, search, in-memory-database

Let's assume we have a ticketing system web page where are displayed tickets (tickets are distributed on multiple pages). Also, in the same page there is a search form which allows filtering.

Those tickets can be modified anytime (delete,update,insert).

So i'm a bit confused. How should the internal architecture look?I've been thinking for a while and I haven't found a clear path.

From my point of view there are 2 ways:

1. use something like an in-memory database and store all the data there. So it's very easy to filter content and to display the requested items. But this solution implies storing a lot of useless data in ram. Like tickets closed or resolved. And those tickets should be there because they can be requested.
2. use database for every search, page display, etc. So there will be a lot of queries. Every search, every page (per user) will result in a database query. Isn't this a bit too much ?

Which solution is better? Are there any better solutions ? Are my concerns futile?

Comment: You would use a database if you need for the data to be persistent over time.

Answer (score 0):

You said "But this solution implies storing a lot of useless data in ram. Like tickets closed or resolved. And those tickets should be there because they can be requested."

If those tickets should be there because they can be requested, then it's not really useless data, is it?

It sounds like a good use case for a hybrid in-memory/persistent database. Keep the open/displayed tickets in in-memory tables. When closed, move them to persistent tables.

Comment: You got your point. When I say useless I mean that the probability of those tickets to be searched is extremely low. But they can be searched. So in 99,99% of cases those tickets just occupy ram. I tought about something similar. But i can't imagine how should I implement the search function because there are two places to search.

Comment: I can envision a few options. Assuming the hybrid in-mem/persistent database system can hold both types of tables in the same database, then join the two tables and query with an 'or' condition on the relevant fields of the two tables.

Or, have a separate query function (and visual element) to query the closed/resolved cases. Could be inconvenient for the user.

Or, just use a conventional persistent database system and acknowledge that the cache will do its job and keep the "hot" data in memory.

Comment: Ok. What data should I cache ? Or how should I cache data ? Are search query relevant to be cached ?

Comment: WRT: Or, just use a conventional persistent database system and acknowledge that the cache will do its job and keep the "hot" data in memory.

The DBMS will do this for you. In most DBMS, the only control you have over the cache is deciding how much system memory to allocate to the database cache. Some DBMS give you more control, such as to pre-warm the cache, or give certain tables higher priority so that pages of those tables are less likely to be pushed out of the cache. It's very DBMS-specific, though.